# Find all $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ twice continuously differentiable, such that $f'(x)=f(-x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find all $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ twice continuously differentiable, such that $f'(x)=f(-x)$.

Since $f$ is twice differentiable we have also $f''(x)=-f'(-x)$. Thus $f''(x)=-f(x)$.

Let $f(x)=e^{rx}$. Then $r^2 e^{rx}+e^{rx}=e^{rx}(r^2+1) \implies r\in\{i,-i\}$.

Because of linearity, $f(x)=Ae^{-ix}+Be^{ix}$ for some constants $A$ and $B$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What you have done is correct, but there is a relation betwen $A$ and $B$, which you find if you differentiate and look at $f'(x)=f(-x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct but incomplete.

You have proved that there are some $A,B$ such as $$
f(x) = Ae^{ix} + Be^{-ix}
$$
but all such functions are not solutions of the original problem.

---

To end  this exercise:
assume that $f(x)$ has the given form, and $f(x) \in \Bbb R$ and $f'(x) = f(-x)$. You will find additional relations that $A,B$ has to verify.

Comment: Good point! Thank you.